# Is the PostGIS Raster primary key required to be named rid?

Tags: postgis, raster, table, postgis-raster

In all examples from the [PostGIS Raster reference](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/RT_reference.html) the primary key in tables with a raster column is named `rid`. I wonder if that naming is expected by any functionality of PostGIS itself or any client software connecting to PostGIS (such as mapserver for instance).

In other words:

Is the name `rid` for the primary key in raster tables a requirement, or can I use `id` as a primary key without running in to trouble?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary key can be named whatever you want. The use of **rid** in the docs is following the convention set by the use of **gid** in PostGIS geometry docs.